# Explanation of a proof of $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ using the epsilon-delta definition of limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I am reading this proof of $\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}\right)=1$ by using epsilon delta technique, directly applied from the epsilon delta definition of limit.

[image]

All the steps are understood except the circle red one.

I don't understand where does the $x^2$ come from? I am bit stumped, perhaps the proof leaves out some steps that I need to trace.

Thank you!

Comment: Please use [more informative titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) in future. I think a great deal of questions on this site could be titled 'Being stumped, need a little bit of help'.

Comment: Actually, it seems an unnecessarily long proof. If you accept that $cos(x) \leq \frac{sin(x)}{x} \leq 1$, then the proof is complete; $ \frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is sandwiched by 1.

Comment: @Arash I think the idea was to prove this directly using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit. It is possible that the author hadn't introduced the sandwich theorem to the reader by the time this proof was given.

Comment: @Arash yeah, you know I am not a big fan of epsilon delta proof. Apart from some contrived examples, it is not very practical. There are other techniques to prove this much more conveniently and elegantly. For example, for this limit, expanding $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ in Taylor series and let $x$->0 will show it clearly. All it is taken is 2-3 lines.

Comment: @Arash But you need to get a hang on epsilon delta convention, for it is used to define other more advanced concepts, like uniform continuity, uniform and pointwise convergence. In general, I think epsilon deltas are not very intuitive definitions. But I am not the one who make a call on math education so what do I know. I just need to complete it to pass exams.

Comment: Actually relying on Taylor expansions is out of the picture. It results in a circular reasoning. But I personally prefer the geometrical premise along with sandwich theorem in this particular problem.

Comment: And if I may suggest, try proving the derivations of sinc at zero. That’s fun too.

Comment: @Arash, well, you are quite right there, because you need a thorough definitions of limit (limit from the left and from the right) to introduce the concept of derivative. So if you want to build the concepts logically, you are not allowed to use derivatives.

Comment: @But context is everything. I have taken an early Calc II before dropping out because my family moved to another state, so I know what are derivatives and Taylor series. Personally, I love series the most out of all mathematical concepts you study in Calc, so I prefer it. Haha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\sin x| \le |x|$ implies $\sin^2 x \le x^2$, and on $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, $\cos x \ge 0$ hence $1 + \cos x \ge 1$ and $$\frac{1}{1 + \cos x} \le 1.$$  Combining these results yields $$\frac{\sin^2 x}{1 + \cos x} \le \frac{x^2}{1 + \cos x} \le x^2.$$

Comment: You are my hero, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That comes from $|\sin(x)|<|x|$ on the second line of your "solution" and also
$$
1+\cos x>1
$$
since $\cos x>0$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Why the quote for solution? I guess it is more accurate to say it is a proof, is that what you mean? :)

Comment: @JamesWarthington: "Solution" is written explicitly in your picture; I just meant to refer to it. Nothing fancy...

Answer (score 1):

Observe that : $\cos x > 0, \forall x \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ ,and $0 \le |\sin x | \le |x|$ as well. This implies $\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{1+\cos x} \le \sin^2 x \le x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You always have $\vert \sin x \vert \le \vert x\vert$.

And for $x$ close to zero $\cos x \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore

$$0 \le \frac{1}{1 +\cos x} \le \frac{2}{3}.$$